# Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I do all configs but it still did'nt works.
I have no ca cert in my folders.

```
# The full hostname
hostname=***************@gmail.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=************@gmail.com
AuthPass=*************
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you done? Where is the code?

Comment: I want to send an email I also did all configuration But it does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't write English very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it by changing hostname to localhost.